# Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback for audio recorder

Tags: java, android

I have an app that allows you to hold a button to record a message through the mic, and on release it will stop recording and play it back. However, holding the button, saying a message and then releasing it creates this huge error:

> 10-15 21:19:42.539 20088-20088/com.example.lbwde.senioraid E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4
>   10-15 21:19:42.539 20088-20088/com.example.lbwde.senioraid E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   10-15 21:19:42.539 20088-20088/com.example.lbwde.senioraid E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   10-15 21:19:42.541 20088-20088/com.example.lbwde.senioraid E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
>           at com.example.lbwde.senioraid.ChatActivity.stopRecording(ChatActivity.java:539)

Here is the code:

```
private FloatingActionButton = voiceMsg;
private MediaRecorder audioRecord;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private String audioOutput;
```

In the `onCreate`:

```
    voiceMsg = findViewById(R.id.voiceMsg);
    audioOutput = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audiomsg.3gpp";

    voiceMsg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                try {

                    startRecording();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stopRecording();
                try {
                    playRecording();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

And the recording/playback methods:

```
private void startRecording() throws Exception {
    ditchRecorder();
    File output = new File (audioOutput);
    if (output.exists()) output.delete();

    audioRecord = new MediaRecorder();
    audioRecord.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    audioRecord.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    audioRecord.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    audioRecord.setOutputFile(audioOutput);
    audioRecord.prepare();
    audioRecord.start();
}

private void playRecording() throws Exception {
    ditchMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioOutput);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private void ditchMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopPlayback() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
private void stopRecording() {
    if (audioRecord != null) {
        audioRecord.stop();
    }
}

private void ditchRecorder() {
    if (audioRecord != null) {
        audioRecord.release();
    }
}
```

I have had similar errors in the past which were solved with adding short delays to code execution but this time it resulted in more errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be managing states of the [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) or [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) incorrectly. You even get `java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop` what clearly says that something is wrong with your states. Have a look at the state diagram of the `MediaRecorder` from the official Android documentation.

[image: MediaRecorder State Diagram]

I see that you're releasing `MediaRecorder` with `recorder.release()` method before recording and doing the same with `MediaPlayer`. I think it's incorrect. According to documentation, `MediaRecorder` object cannot be re-used after release. Try to re-organize your state management to make it correct according to the documentation.